# IFormFile without deprecated Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I use `IFormFile` in class library, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features` has become deprecated. What kind nugget package I need now, for `IFormFile` in .Net 7

Comment: This article explains the change: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/6.0/microsoft-aspnetcore-http-features-package-split

Comment: be aware that .net is currently in the middle of major "restructuring" where many packages had their stable version marked as deprecated, see [announcement](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/217). should your work place disallow non-stable (e.g. preview) releases it should be put forward as consideration.

Answer (score 17):

Please read this document:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore

Delete any packages like Microsoft.Extensions.Features in the .csproj file and instead reference the framework.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Yes, I also saw this solution, but I think it will not be the right approach.

Comment: @giorgi02 worked fine for me in my .net 7 console app when I ran into the same issue

Comment: This is the correct answer. People might think this is equivalent to fetching the whole AspNetCore lib and their dependencies (I know I did at first), but it's not. This is basically telling the project that this whole "AspNetCore" thing is now part of the shared .Net framework and can be used safely, without requiring any additional dependency at compile- or run-time.

Answer (score 1):

> I use IFormFile in class library, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features
> has become deprecated. What kind nugget package I need now, for
> IFormFile in .Net 7

Actually, in .NET 7 [IFormFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-7.0) has been integrated automatically by default. In addition, if you use IFormFile for [streaming any file operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0) you no longer required additional package because IFormFile which is belongs  to [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features?view=aspnetcore-7.0) assembly and [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http?view=aspnetcore-7.0) namaspace has been included within .Net 7. Thus, you don't need to install or include any additional nuget package for that.

You can have a look at following information:

[image]

**How To Use In Class Library:**

In order to use IFormFile within class library within .NET 7 we can use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http nuget package. Although its out of support scope but still be usuable as asp.netcore 2.2 considered as unique category and continued its legacy.

[image]

Example:

```
namespace IFromFileTestClassLibrary
{
    public class UploadFiles
    {
        public async Task<string> FileHandelerMethod(CreateProfileViewModel requestModel)
        {
            string filePath = "file saving path";
            var path = Path.Combine(filePath, "Images", requestModel.Photo!.FileName);
            if (requestModel.Photo.Length > 0)
            {
                using var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
                await requestModel.Photo.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
            return requestModel.ImageURL = path;
        }
    }


    public class CreateProfileViewModel
    {
        public string? ProfileName { get; set; }
        public string? DisplayPhoto { get; set; }
        public string? ImageURL { get; set; }
        public IFormFile? Photo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Note:** You can [refer to this official document for more details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: thank you to answer. yes it is true, I know this, but I want use `IFormFile` into class library

Comment: For class library we can attachd `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` package into your library which still continuing its legacy. I have updated the answer for better clarity. Let me know if I can assist on this further.

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` is also deprecated, I want not deprecated package

Comment: Thanks for your response, I got your point in that scnario, you might need to wait until next release if theres any.